# Bootstrap alert's taking up two lines

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Just wondering if there is a way that I can have a bootstrap alert text only display on one line without it taking up the entire width of the page:

http://codepen.io/EuanR/pen/JdqYrp

As you can see in the codepen, The alert is taking up two lines, however if I remove `position: absolute;` the alert will take up the entire width page.

Code:

HTML:

```
<div class="topleft">
  <div class="alert alert-danger fade in">
    <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times; &nbsp;</a>
    <div class="innermessage">
      Error: All fields must be filled!
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.topleft {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
}

.innermessage {
    padding-right:2px;
}
```

Comment: change the width of `.topleft`, because `position:absolute` will make unset width weird

Comment: @DanielCheung I would change the width, but then it could still take up two lines if the alert was long enough, I was just wondering if there was a way so that the alert is as long as the text.

Comment: `text-overflow: ellipsis;`? `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet` will turn into `Lorem ipsum dolor...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change `.innermessage` width to 225px, and adjust accordingly to your alert message width.

```
.innermessage {
    padding-right:2px;
    width: 225px;
}
```

```css
.topleft {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 10px;
    padding: 5px;

}

.innermessage {
 padding-right:2px;
  width: 225px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
      <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

      <!-- Optional theme -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

      <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js">    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div class="topleft">
        <div class="alert alert-danger fade in">
          <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria label="close">&times; &nbsp;</a>
        <div class="innermessage">
          Error: All fields must be filled!
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

It will be 225px no matter what, regardless of screen size, and as long as the width is bigger than the text width, it'll stay on one line.